# Gulp clean not working when in an array of tasks

Tags: gulp, yii2, composer-php

I am using yii2 to build a web service. And to help me to put together all the  things I use gulp. I have a file structure similar to this

gulpfile.js
  index.php
  basics/
   -composer.json
  -vendor/

after you get all the dependencies using composer they save into vendor folder. The problem is that for some reason yii2 saves bower asset in a folder called `bower-asset`, but it will only work if the folder is called `bower`. So I wrote these two tasks to help me with this. task one copies the content of bower-asset folder into bower folder in the same directory and the second task deletes `bower-asset` folder. My problem occurs when task two is ran from default task. Then it returns an error like this

```
[15:11:20] Starting 'bower-del'...
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/Me/Documents/mamp/dumb/game/basic/vendor/bower-asset/jquery/dist'
    at Error (native)
```

It also appears if I try to tell task to to wait for task one to be finished before task two starts like

`gulp.task('bower-del', ['bower-copy'], function () {`

The thing that surprises me the most is that if I run task two by itself ie `gulp bower-del` it deletes the folder no problem.

I have taken other tasks from my gulp file for simplicity purposes.

This is what my gulp tasks look like:

```
// Copies bower-asset into bower folder
gulp.task('bower-copy', function(){
    gulp.src('./basic/vendor/bower-asset/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('basic/vendor/bower/'));
});

// Deletes old bower-asset folder
gulp.task('bower-del', function () {
    return gulp.src('./basic/vendor/bower-asset/', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('default', ['bower-copy', 'bower-del']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run de bower-del in sequence. In my [SkeletonSpa](https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA/) I have the same issue with cleaning before a build. Here I have 2 tasks `clean` and `build`, where the `build` task should only run when the `clean` task is finished, eg. they should not run in parallel.

My implementation is as follows:

```
gulp.task('build', (cb) => {
  let runSequence = require('run-sequence');

  runSequence('clean', ['info', 'styles', 'scripts', 'images', 'copy'], 'todo', cb);
});
gulp.task('clean', ['clear-cache'], () => {
  let del = require('del');
  let vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');

  return gulp.src([settings.dist, settings.reports])
  .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});
```

This will do the trick. Just take a look at the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) plugin and implement it ;-)